# Duty of Student

Tags: vipassana, meditation-insight, traditions

I have list of Question can any one suggest answer of these question from me from Buddhist tradition.

- what is duty of student?
- what are elements that useful for student from Destruction?
- How Vipasana Meditation help student?

Answer (score 1):

Nyom Dheeraj Kumar and interested,

Having raised such a question "what is duty of student?", i.e. "what are my duties" at first and continuing place, is a good sign. If having patiently waited, as well. And if now carefully attentive reading all and by it understand alot already, seldom one knows, it looks pretty good to meet soon the right teacher. Sadhu and [mudita](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/dictionary/mudita)

The general duties in relation to teacher are: [DN 31](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara_en.html)

> "In five ways, young householder, a pupil should minister to a teacher as the South:
>
> (i) by rising from the seat in salutation,
>   (ii) by attending on him,
>   (iii) by eagerness to learn,
>   (iv) by personal service,
>   (v) by respectful attention while receiving instructions.

One might be interested about duties of Dhamma-disciples:

[[Q&A] Proper way to ask a teacher to become their student - duties](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8135.msg13971.html#msg13971)

Worthy to note is that there are no real defined relations between monks and laypeople, see here: [Different kind of teacher-student relationships](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8135.msg12396.html#msg12396)

And that layteacher might give often no change to fulfill duties since their are after other compensations (that's a warn sign for monks as well).

Since monks are actually not given to teach if there are signs of lack of respect, good to make one familar with: [Respect and veneration](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2015.msg13980.html#post_ea3)

And the three requisites to be able to receive Dhamma: [Respect, Confidence and Patient](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8233.0.html)

PS: take care of body gesture, such as standing, higher, closed up like crossing hands... and the questions: "what are elements that useful for student from Destruction? How Vipasana Meditation help student?" are not proper and may fit just to markets.

*[Note that this is not given that one increases his debts by trade, exchange, stacks and Buddh-ism but to go beyond relations and dependency]*